# Find the maximal k such that there exists a point covered by k intervals

Tags: algorithm

Suppose that n closed intervals [a[i], b[i]] on the real line are given (i = 1..n). Find the maximal k such that there exists a point covered by k intervals (the maximal number of “layers”). The number of operations should be of order nlogn.

There is a solution about it.
[Hint. Sort all the left and right endpoints of the intervals together. While sorting, assume that the left endpoint precedes the right endpoint located at the same point of the real line. Then move from left to right counting the number of layers. When we cross the left endpoint, increase the number of layers by 1; when we cross the right endpoint, decrease the number of layers by 1. Please note that two adjacent intervals are processed correctly; that is, the left endpoint precedes the right endpoint according to our convention.]

My question is, how do I know if the point encountered is left endpoint or right endpoint? Do I need extra spaces to take record?

Comment: "extra" over what? it doesn't seem you can do this in place anyway

Comment: Either you store for each point whether it is a left or right point, or you store the left and right points in two seperate lists.

Answer (score 0):

The question itself contains the steps of the expected algorithm, almost a pseudo-code.

I turned the description into a *python 3* program as an excercise:

```
def prefix_sum(seq, acc = 0):
  for i in seq:
    acc += i
    yield acc

def count_layers(intervals):
  endpoints = sorted([(s, -1) for s,e in intervals] + [(e, +1) for s,e in intervals])
  return -min(prefix_sum(delta for _,delta in endpoints))

print(count_layers([[2,3],[1,2]]))
```

Tested with:

```
def test(intervals):
  print()
  print('Test')
  for s,e in intervals:
    print(' ' * s + '-' * (e - s + 1))
  print('Answer:', count_layers(intervals))

TEST_CASES = [
  [ [ 1, 5], [ 4, 9], [ 2, 4], [ 6,12], ],
  [ [ 1, 3], [ 3, 5], [ 7, 9], [ 5, 7], ],
  [ [ 3, 4], [ 1, 2], ],
  [ [ 2, 3], [ 1, 2], ],
]

for test_case in TEST_CASES:
  test(test_case)
```